# How to connect to MySQL server in LAN?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, mysql, database, lan

Here is the technical description.

My laptop's config:

- IP Adress:192.168.2.5
- MySQL Server 5.0 on port 3306
- Operating System: Ubuntu
- The database is in this machine

My friend's laptop config:

- IP Adress:192.168.2.4
- MySQL Server 5.0 on port 3306
- Operating System: Windows XP

Both are on a wireless LAN connected through a Belkin router (192.168.2.1). I put this but its not working:

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.5:3306/Database"
```

How can I configure things connect to this database?

Comment: Questions about home networks and personal computers are off-topic per the [faq]

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is a TCP protocol running on port 3306 by defauly, hence there is nothing special beyond ensure that you have enabled binding to a public IP address in the `/etc/my.cnf` file;

```
port            = 3306
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

On the client you would need to install the jdbc drivers for MySQL;

For windows XP they can be downloaded from here;
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

For ubuntu, there are package version in the repository;

```
# aptitude search mysql | grep JDBC
p   libmysql-java                   - Java database (JDBC) driver for MySQL
```

You can use any client, mysql provide a workbence tools product;
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html

or you can use Libreoffice and their database connection to view the tables;
http://www.libreoffice.org/features/base/

Or use a scripting language like php;
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

or even just the command line client;

```
$ mysql -h192.168.2.5 -uuserXXX -e "show databases;"
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema | 
| badger1             | 
| cacti              |
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer.
my friend can access to my database in windows xp but my goal is to access to ** his database in ubuntu**.
i have windows xp

Comment: how do you wish to access it?, is the database already running in Ubuntu, or do you need to install it?

Comment: $ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:

mysql> use mysql

mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'192.168.2.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-root-password'; 
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Answer (score 0):

This might sound stupid but have you checked if your Ubuntu machine has its firewall running? That has tripped me up a few times on both Windows and Linux.

A quick check is to run:
`sudo iptables -L`

Here is a how-to from the ubuntu site: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured remote access for your MySQL server ? If not, read [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html).